# Remove an item from a collection of Lists

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections, linq-to-objects

I'm pretty sure that this is a no brainer for you gurus, but I'm having trouble thinking straight today.  I have a collection of lists that I acquired using this LINQ code:

```
var errPRNlines = File.ReadAllLines(myFile.FullName.ToString(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1250))
.Skip(1)
.Where (f => f.ToString().Contains("Not available"))
.Select(line => line.Split(new[] { "  " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
.ToList();
```

The results are:

List1:

```
"GCE" 
Not available
""
"RES"
9.97000000
9.99000000
```

List2:

```
"WRK.UN"
Not available
""
"INT"
16.22000000
16.22000000
```

My question is how can I preserve my collection of lists but exclude the 3rd element in each of those lists?  Is it easier to create a new list or just remove the item?  So, my ending collection of lists should look like:

List1:

```
"GCE" 
Not available
"RES"
9.97000000
9.99000000
```

List2:

```
"WRK.UN"
Not available
"INT"
16.22000000
16.22000000
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Tim & @Carsten for the pointers.  Here's the updated code:

```
var errPRNlines = File.ReadAllLines(myFile.FullName.ToString(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1250))
.Skip(1)
.Where (line => line.Contains("Not available"))
.Select(line => 
    line.Split(new[] { "  " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where((col, index) => index!=2))
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx)-Overload to do this:

```
.Where ((f, index) => index != 2 && f.ToString().Contains("Not available"))
```

Comment: I assume that it's not the thrid line but the third column in each line he wants to skip. So this `Where` is too early.

Comment: you might be right - was only looking at the examples (not very clear) - in this case you would have to put a similar Where inside the next Select - I don't think it's a big deal)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the indexer in a [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) to skip it:

```
var errPRNlines = File.ReadAllLines(myFile.FullName.ToString(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1250))
.Skip(1)
.Where (line => line.Contains("Not available"))
.Select(line => line.Split(new[] { "  " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
.Where((col, index) => index!=2)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Your code took out my List2 completely.  I just want to remove the 3rd element in each of those lists.

Comment: Thanks @Tim.  Along with Carsten's suggestion, I was able to use your code more effectively.  I've pasted the right code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you always want to remove just the third element in the list, you can use List1.RemoveAt(2) and List2.RemoveAt(2) to remove the third element from the list.